# How to make scrollbar in lesser width/length compared to the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a container which scrolls horizontally. I'm in need of creating the scroll bar that does not has the container width. For example

```
  -------------------------------------------
  -                                         -
  -        My scrollable container          -
  -                                         -
  -------------------------------------------

        -----------------------------
          (this should be the scrollbar)
```

My current implementation is like this

```
  -------------------------------------------
  -                                         -
  -        My scrollable container          -
  -                                         -
  -------------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------------
```

I tried many things including adding paddings/margins and also tried something called scrollbar-gutter. Nothing worked. How can i get a scrollbar with spaces between so that it does not has the full width of the container.

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: @ShivamJha i refered this actually. But it did not explain how to do something like what i need

Comment: Add width property to `<element>::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` or `<element>::-webkit-scrollbar-track`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add ad `margin-left` and `margin-right` (in case of horizontal scrolling) to the `scrollbar-track` to make the scrollbar look smaller like so

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/6rpzxuqg/1/